# kubectl create from inside pod

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I have a running jenkins pod and i am trying to execute following commands:

```
sudo kubectl --kubeconfig /opt/jenkins_home/admin.conf apply -f /opt/jenkins_home/ab-kubernetes/ab-back.yml
```

It is giving following error:

**Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource**

What cound go wrong here?

`ab-back.yml` file

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dg-back-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: dg-core-backend-d
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      nodePort: 30003
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dg-core-backend-d
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dg-core-backend-d
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dg-core-java
        image: ab/dg-springboot-java:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["sh"]
        args: ["-c", "/root/post-deployment.sh"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        # livenessProbe:
        #   httpGet:
        #     path: /
        #     port: 8080
        env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: xxx
```

**UPDATE:**

`kubectl version` is as follows :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-27T20:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T16:24:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

On applying logs as `--v=4`,`kubectl apply` is working and giving logs as follows :

```
I0702 11:40:17.721604    1601 merged_client_builder.go:159] Using in-cluster namespace
I0702 11:40:17.734648    1601 decoder.go:224] decoding stream as YAML
service/dg-back-svc created
deployment.extensions/dg-core-backend-d created
```

but `kubectl create` is giving error as :

```
I0702 11:41:12.265490    1631 helpers.go:201] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server could not find the requested resource",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "causes": [
      {
        "reason": "UnexpectedServerResponse",
        "message": "unknown"
      }
    ]
  },
  "code": 404
}]
```

Also on doing `kubectl get pods --v=10`,it is giving log as :

```
Response Body: {
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "only the following media types are accepted: application/json, application/yaml, application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf",
  "reason": "NotAcceptable",
  "code": 406
}
I0702 12:34:27.542564    2514 request.go:1099] body was not decodable (unable to check for Status): Object 'Kind' is missing in '{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "only the following media types are accepted: application/json, application/yaml, application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf",
  "reason": "NotAcceptable",
  "code": 406
}'
No resources found.
I0702 12:34:27.542813    2514 helpers.go:201] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "unknown (get pods)",
  "reason": "NotAcceptable",
  "details": {
    "kind": "pods",
    "causes": [
      {
        "reason": "UnexpectedServerResponse",
        "message": "unknown"
      }
    ]
  },
  "code": 406
}]
```

Comment: can u try to share your ab-back.yml?

Comment: I can share but it is running fine from outside pod on normal cli.

Comment: Can u try enable the debug log, such as --v=4 after your command?

Comment: @Tim,i have updated the question with logs.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in versions, try to use the old version of the client or upgrade the server. kubectl supports one version forward and backward skew:

From [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/release/versioning.md#supported-releases-and-component-skew)

> a client should be skewed no more than one minor version from the
>   master, but may lead the master by up to one minor version. For
>   example, a v1.3 master should work with v1.1, v1.2, and v1.3 nodes,
>   and should work with v1.2, v1.3, and v1.4 clients.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes server doesnt have this `extensions/v1beta1` this resources. thats the reason why you cannot create `dg-core-backend-d`
You can check this by typing `kubectl api-versions`

Comment: The output of `kubectl api-versions` is as follows:`apps/v1beta1
authentication.k8s.io/v1
authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
authorization.k8s.io/v1
authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
autoscaling/v1
batch/v1
certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
extensions/v1beta1
policy/v1beta1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1
storage.k8s.io/v1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1` and `extensions/v1beta1` is present in it.

Comment: if that resource is found, could you pls try running like this `sudo kubectl --kubeconfig /opt/jenkins_home/admin.conf apply -f /opt/jenkins_home/ab-kubernetes/ab-back.yml --api-version=v1beta1 --v=10` Lets see how it is behaving

Comment: `apply` is working perfectly.Please refer above updates in question.

Comment: Oops! I meant the `create` like this `sudo kubectl --kubeconfig /opt/jenkins_home/admin.conf create -f /opt/jenkins_home/ab-kubernetes/ab-back.yml --api-version=v1beta1 --v=10` sorry

Comment: I have hunch that kubernetes server version that this resource having conflict. like in this https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/9945 but beyond this I couldnt see how to help you with this. :)