# Kubectl mismatch version between client and server result in stuck pods in Termination

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

What happened:
Installed kubctl-cli throgh brew. At the time on my pc kubectl version version was 1.11.0 and the server was 1.9.3.
While I was working on my cluster I tried to delete a pod named X, the command got stuck so I had to stop it (ctrl+c) and pod X got stuck in a Termination state.
I tried to SSH into the hosted node and manually delete the pod but no success, also tried th delete the pod with --force and/--period 0/--now.

Is there a way I can remove the pod?

What you expected to happen:

Pod X was deleted successfully from the cluster

How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):

Install kubctl-cli version 1.11.0 on server 1.9.3

Environment:

```
Cloud provider or hardware configuration:
AWS using kops
Kernel (e.g. uname -a):
Darwin h-MacBook-Pro-sl-ido.local 17.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.6.0: Tue May 8 15:22:16 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.61.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: i don't think versions mismatch is the reason...could you provide more info? (get, describe, `.yml`s?)

Comment: .yml for what? I logged into different machine and everything worked as expected. downgrade my kubectl version and everything worked as excepted. so i'm quite sure that this was the problem

Answer (score 3):

I provided [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51138459/9485673) to same problem:

> From [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/release/versioning.md#supported-releases-and-component-skew)
>
> a client should be skewed no more than one minor version from the
>   master, but may lead the master by up to one minor version. For
>   example, a v1.3 master should work with v1.1, v1.2, and v1.3 nodes,
>   and should work with v1.2, v1.3, and v1.4 clients

Comment: my question is how to remove the pods that got stuck, i know that the vast mismatch caused this

Comment: [ido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3921794/ido) You could check what version is available `brew info kubernetes-cli` and then use command  `brew switch kubernetes-cli $version` to switch to previous one.